# Show filtered value in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi

Let's say I have those values : 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lhlS.png)

I would like to filter on the value 4 in "Colonne 3" but then, I would like to display the other value if "Colonne 2" has other values.

For example, John and Jean have 4. But they also have other values. Then I would like to show that John has 8 and 7 and Jean has 7.

I hope that it's clear enough for you.

Thanks !

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Can you show and example of what you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Power BI is limited on how well it can do this without significant coding, but I believe I've gotten you close:

- Create a table visual for your data (all 4 columns), this will be Table1
- Create a slicer using only column 3, (This will be Slicer1)
- With Slicer1 selected go to >Format>Edit Interactions, hover over Table1 and make sure it has the 'Filter' icon selected
- Create another slicer, using only column 2 (This will be Slicer2)
- With Slicer2 selected, make sure the filter interaction with Slicer1 is 'None' and the filter interaction with Table1 is 'None'
- Select Slicer1 again and make sure the filter interaction with Slicer2 is set to 'filter'
- Make a copy of Table1, this will be Table2.
- Select Slicer1 and make sure the filter interaction with Table2 is set to 'None'
- Select Slicer2 and make sure the filter interaction with Table2 is set to 'filter'

So now when you choose a value in Slicer1, Table1 will be filtered to that value and Slicer2 will be filtered to the names of those values, all you need to do is select the filtered values in the slicer and this will filter Table2.

Here are some screenshots:

**1. All are unfiltered**

[image: Screenshot(1)]

**2. Filter Slicer1**

[image: Screenshot(2)]

**3. Filter Slicer2**

[image: Screenshot(3)]

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Thanks!